# Access VBA error with DCOUNT

Tags: ms-access, vba

Access is telling me the following is improper, but I can't see how.

```
cnt = DCount("recid", "dbo_HR_EmployeeTrainings", "EnteredDateTime > '" & CStr(DateAdd("Minute", -1, Date)) + "'")
```

Error given is `Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be `n`, not `minute`.

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dateadd-function-HA001228810.aspx

Why are your dates stored as strings?

Re comment try:

```
 DCount("recid", "dbo_HR_EmployeeTrainings", "EnteredDateTime > DateAdd('n', -1, Date())")
```

Comment: Your wondering about the CSTR() and the single quotes?  The dates aren't stored as strings, that's just something I tried when my original statement didn't work.  I really don't need the conversion.

Comment: I have added a note. If that does not suit, the date delimiter is hash (#). `... Date = #" & Date & "#"`. Watch out for locale problems.